# Use ffmpeg to extract/remix audio from/into video

Tags: ffmpeg

Working on a Mac, I have a bunch of `.mkv` files that I want to extract the audio from, then use an ML model I have in order to translate them and then mix them back into the video.

For the extraction phase, I am running:
`ffmpeg -i {input_video}.mkv -map 0:a -c copy {output_audio}.aac`
however I am getting these errors:

```
[adts @ 0x130708b30] Only AAC streams can be muxed by the ADTS muxer
[out#0/adts @ 0x6000031943c0] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
[aost#0:1/copy @ 0x13070a050] Error initializing output stream:
```

which I suspect are because of subtitles, seeing these warnings earlier in the output:

```
[matroska,webm @ 0x130704260] Could not find codec parameters for stream 4 (Subtitle: (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[matroska,webm @ 0x130704260] Could not find codec parameters for stream 5 (Subtitle:  (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[matroska,webm @ 0x130704260] Could not find codec parameters for stream 6 (Attachment: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
```

The only command that has worked for me so far is
`ffmpeg -i {input_video}.mkv -vn -c:a aac {output_aduio}.wav` which however created a completely empty audio file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Comment: First, examine the `.mkv` file to understand its structure, especially the audio stream. Based on the audio format identified, use an appropriate codec. Your problem is that the audio stream in your `.mkv` file might not be in AAC format, but you're trying to mux it into an AAC container.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked:

`ffmpeg -i {input_video}.mkv -vn -ac 2 {output_audio}.aac`

I guess what did the trick was specifying the audio channel and stating no video.

Comment: *trick was specifying the audio channel* --> no, it was omitting `-c copy`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).